# Remember me table indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, mariadb

I am creating a table in MariaDB to store "remember me"-cookie values:

```
CREATE TABLE u_remember_me (
    u_user_common_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    lookup_key       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    token_hash       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    created          DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    INDEX (u_user_common_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (u_user_common_id) REFERENCES u_user_common (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (lookup_key),
    UNIQUE KEY (lookup_key, token_hash)
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci ENGINE InnoDB;
```

I am always going to lookup by the lookup_key field and have therefore chosen that as a primary key (random string). The column u_user_common_id can not be set as primary key since a user can have multiple (lookup_key, token_hash) assigned because of multiple browsers or computers. Is lookup_key a bad choice for a primary key (performance, insert etc.?). Also.. Should I set the primary key to (lookup_key, token_hash) instead and drop the UNIQUE constraint? The reason why I have chosen not to have a surrogate key is because it will never be used, but I am not sure if that is a good decision either (I need lookup_key to be indexed anyway).

Comment: Hey @TankSneeze, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Given the nature of your question, I believe that you should post it under https://dba.stackexchange.com/ rather than here.

Comment: You state that "I am always going to lookup by the `lookup_key`", so that is all you really need an index on. If you're not querying on other columns, then you can simply use `lookup_key` as the only column in the index, to keep your indexes from getting too bloated.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarcelloGrechiLins :) Also, thank you for the tip about wrong place for posting :) Sorry about that! And thanks to you too @RToyo! I can probably drop the UNIQUE constraint since it does not matter if two users have the same token_hash (even if that is highly unlikely). This way I can save unnecessary space usage for an extra index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not figured out what depends on what.

Is the `lookup_key` (random string) associated with a single user?  If so, `PRIMARY KEY(lookup_key)` and get rid of token_hash.

If the user can connect from different browsers *and* you want something different to happen, then you have not specified any data that will be different.